# A Good, Complete Mono compatible game engine for C#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am a linux enthusiast and developer, I've gotten back into c# development after a hiatus from my switch to linux. Are there any good game engines/libraries that are actively developed, free, and linux compatible? I have seen Axiom, And am considering it (although the example sigsegv's every time), brume, monogame, opentk, and netgore. MonoGame looks to be the best, but I just wanted to know if anyone else had a good library I could use.

Comment: This is an excellent question for gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I bet MonoGame can be the good choice, because it is in active development (and seems to evolve fast). It is still not complete yet (3D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is a good one. Using it you can deploy to: Windows, Linux, OSX (Mac), Android, iPhone, XBox, Playstation and WebBrowser (chrome, opera, firefox, IE; needs a lightweight plugin). Soon deploy to Flash will be added.

Comment: Care to elaborate where you got this information? Unity3d does **not** officially support Linux, hence the lack of Linux-related downloads from the mainpage of Unity3d.

Comment: agreed, thanks for the answer though